# PrettyFaces redirect doesn't work with preRenderView event

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, prettyfaces

i have a preRender view event in my bean, and i make some validation in it on the user, and when some condition occur, i redirect the user to login page using prettyFaces, but the redirection doesn't seem to work, i don't know why, here's the code:

JSF:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.preRender}" />
```

Managed Bean:

```
public String preRender() {
        log.debug("preRender myPage for user " + userId);
        try {
            User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
            if (!user.isSomeCondition()) {
                log.debug("Bad Condition");
                return "pretty:login";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in preRender myPage for user "
                    + userId);
            return "pretty:login";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't navigate by returning a string in action listener methods. It would be completely ignored. It is only possible in real action methods as provided by `<h:commandXxx action="...">`.

What you can do instead, is to manually invoke the [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) .

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
NavigationHandler navigator = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
navigator.handleNavigation(context, null, "pretty:login");
```

Comment: @BalusC, how to navigate in preRender if not using prettyfaces ?

Comment: @Mah: The same way. Just use a normal outcome value like `"login.xhtml"` instead of `"pretty:login"`. Alternatively, just use `ExternalContext#redirect()`.